# C# Script to Convert the content of Excel sheet to Tabular format

Tags: excel, tabular, format-conversion

I have a BI report which needs the source data to be in a tabular form in XLS format.

The source data is triggered to my system from a tool on a daily basis. It is in .xls format, but with simple formatting. When feeding this data into my BI report, it must be converted to tables.

Instead of manually updating the Excel file daily, I want to automate the process. I have the script which downloads the Excel file from the client tool and saves it to my local system.

So in one line I need a method which will do the below:

Input:

[image: BEFORE]

Desired Output:

[image: AFTER]

Note - I am writing the script in C# windows application.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample Java code which can be used.

```
    import org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTable;
    import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumn;
    import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumns;
    import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableStyleInfo;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Main{

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\x228458\\Desktop\\ExcelExample.xlsx"));
            XSSFWorkbook my_xlsx_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document);
            XSSFSheet sheet = my_xlsx_workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            int firstrowindex = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
            int lastrowindex = sheet.getLastRowNum();

            int firstcolumnindex = sheet.getRow(0).getFirstCellNum();
            int lastcolumnindex = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
            int numberofcolumns=(lastcolumnindex-firstcolumnindex);

            XSSFTable my_table = sheet.createTable();
            CTTable cttable = my_table.getCTTable();
            CTTableStyleInfo table_style = cttable.addNewTableStyleInfo();
            table_style.setName("TableStyleMedium9");
            table_style.setShowColumnStripes(false);
            table_style.setShowRowStripes(true);
            AreaReference my_data_range = new AreaReference(new CellReference(firstrowindex, firstcolumnindex), new CellReference(lastrowindex, lastcolumnindex-1));
            cttable.setRef(my_data_range.formatAsString());
            cttable.setDisplayName("MYTABLE");
            cttable.setName("Test");
            cttable.setId(2L); //you can use any integer as Id

            CTTableColumns columns = cttable.addNewTableColumns();

            columns.setCount(numberofcolumns);
            for (int i = 0; i < numberofcolumns; i++)
            {
                CTTableColumn column = columns.addNewTableColumn();
                column.setName("Column" + i);
                column.setId(i+1);
            }
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\x228458\\Desktop\\Excel_Format_Table.xlsx");
            my_xlsx_workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
        }
    }
```

NOTE: Apache poi 3.15 jars are used

Comment: Hi, what is c# alternate for ```CTTableStyleInfo table_style = cttable.addNewTableStyleInfo();``` as I could not find ```addNewTableStyleInfo()``` function.
Even ```cttable.tableStyleInfo=new CT_TableStyleInfo();``` this doesn't work.